# Ring with each element finite order but not of finite characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is example of ring **without** identity with each element of finite additive order but not of finite characteristic.

Motivation: A ring **with** identity and having identity of finite additive order is always of finite characteristic

One More Similar Questions:
ring **without zero divisor** with each element of finite additive order but not of finite characteristic.

One More Question:
Ring **with multiplicative identity** with one element of finite additive order(obviously it can't be multiplicative identity of ring) **but not of finite characteristic**

Comment: How do you define order in a ring?

Comment: @LeonAragones presumably additive order, since $R$ is an abelian group under addition.

Comment: @I have made edit also. Sorry have forgotten to mention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

> $$R=\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$$

Then $R$ has elements of arbitrarily large order, hence cannot have a finite characteristic. Note that elements of the direct sum only have finitely many coordinates non-zero, so if $N$ is the largest such for $x\in R$, we have $N!x=0$, i.e. the order of $x$ divides $N!$ and is--in particular--finite.

Comment: Sorry not familiar with notation. Is it Cartesina product of sets. But then we need AC to prove it is non-empty. And as mentioned by AdLibitum, every element not of finite order also

Comment: @Sushil That is not true, the direct sum is not the same as the direct product.

Comment: Note that though every summand in the direct sum has a multiplicative unit, the sum as a whole does not.

Comment: Sorry not familiar with notation as much i can see it is direct product

Comment: @Sushil check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum for details on how direct sums work and how they contrast with direct products. If you look, you can also see directly that $R$ is non-empty, it contains sequences, which you can explicitly construct, such as $(1,0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen the original question has a unit in the motivation but not in the question, so I didn't bother with it. Unless you were talking to the op, in which case nvm.

Comment: @Sushil: The ring written down contains sequences $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ where $a_n\in\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ _and for sufficiently large $n$ the class $a_n$ is the class of $0$_. You can compute with these sequences componentwise. It is clearly a non-trivial commutative ring (without unit).

Comment: @AdamHughes: I was just pointing out that this example does not contradict the true statement in the question that for rings with identity this does not happen.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen cool, just checking!

Comment: @AdamHughes Can we find example where ring has no zero divisor

Comment: @Sushil not possible:  since every element has finite order, but the ring does not have finite characteristic, there exist infinitely many elements of different order (since the orders must go to infinity to make sure there is no characteristic). Select two elements, $x_1,x_2$ of different orders, $n_1, n_2$. There are two cases, either one divides the other, eg. $n_1|n_2$ or $\gcd(n_1,n_2)\not\in \{n_1,n_2\}$ for either $i$. In the latter case $n_2x_1$ is a zero divisor with co-divisor $n_1x_2$. In the former $n_1x_2$ is a zero divisor with co-divisor $x_1$.

Comment: Such a good expanation. @AdamHughes Still come up with a question. Ring with unity with one element of finite additive order but not of finite characteristic

Comment: @AdamHughes clearly ring can't be integral domain because additive order of that element will be that of multiplicative identity with application of distributive law and non-existence of zero divisor

Comment: @Sushil that's even easier, since there's only one element, it must have order $2$, or else $2x$ also has finite order, so we just choose $R=\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

(This answers what the question was *before* the requirement that the ring does not have a unit was added)

If every element in a unital ring $R$ has finite order, in particular the unit element $1_R$ has some finite order $n$ and then $nx=0$ for all $x\in R$. It follows that the orders of the elements of $R$ cannot be unbounded.

Comment: Right but question is for ring without unity

Comment: Mariano, The question was always for no unit, the op just didn't express it very well. (I don't think your answer needs to go away, but it should be said that the content was confusing, not different)

Comment: Well, it was not well expressed in that the requirement for non-unitality was omited! As evinced by what happened, that omission completely changed the question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I suppose one could view it that way, the ambiguity was very strong in the actual question. The clue was that the motivation given was exactly the case you prove, though, so it was probably meant to be reasoned that it wouldn't make sense for him to be asking for a proof of the case which he's already taken as motivation! :-)

Comment: In any case, it's not really important, this is just my thorough side making note since I know some people like such things pointed out.